# How can I access AppSettings from an ActionFilterAttribute in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am currently trying to develop a WebAPI (.NET Core) which has some controller actions that should use HTTP Basic Authentication. To implement this, I have written an ActionFilterAttribute which I can then use in my controller to restrict access to certain actions. This all workes well if I do something like this:

**BasicAuthAttribute.cs**

```
public class BasicAuthAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute{
    private string _username { get; set; }
    private string _password { get; set; }

    public BasicAuthAttribute(string username, string password) {
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext) {
    //do Auth check...
    }
}
```

In the controller I then use it as following:

**SomeController.cs**

```
[BasicAuth("testuser","testpassword")]
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(string id) {
    return new ObjectResult("Test");
}
```

Now I do not want to specify username ond password in SomeController.cs. Instead I would like to store them in appsettings.json. How is it possible to access values stored in appsettings.json in the OnActionExecuting method in the ActionFilterAttribute?

If I change the constructor of BasicAuthAttribute to the following, .Net expects me to pass the settings, which is not possible. Dependency Injection seems not to work here.

```
public BasicAuthAttribute(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings) {}
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated

**UPDATE based on  Set's answer:**

I ended up changing the attribute to a filter. In case anybody else needs it see the working solution below:

**BasicAuthFilter.cs**

```
public class BasicAuthFilter : IActionFilter {

    protected AppSettings _settings { get; set; }

    public BasicAuthAttribute(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings) {
        _settings = appSettings;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {
        //nothing to do here
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext) 
    {
        //do Auth check...
    }
}
```

**SomeController.cs**

```
public class SomeController : Controller {
   [TypeFilter(typeof(BasicAuthFilter))]
   [HttpGet("{id}")]
   public IActionResult Get(string id) {
        return new ObjectResult("Test");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters section in [ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters) explains how to use DI:

> If your filters have dependencies that you need to access from DI, there are several supported approaches. You can apply your filter to a class or action method using one of the following:

- `ServiceFilterAttribute`
- `TypeFilterAttribute`
- `IFilterFactory` implemented on your attribute

Comment: This is the direct link to the DI section referenced here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#dependency-injection