# How can I access AppSettings from an ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to get values from the appsettings.json file in an ActionFilterAttribute. I followed this link ([How can I access AppSettings from an ActionFilterAttribute in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423194/how-can-i-access-appsettings-from-an-actionfilterattribute-in-asp-net-core)), but it does not help me, because I need to pass parameters to my custom filter and also use some from appsettings.json. For example

//Filter.cs

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ThrottleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Count { get; set; }

    private static MemoryCache Cache { get; } = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)
    {
        //Compare this.Count with GetValueFromAppSettings.json
    }
}
```

//Controller.cs

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : BaseController
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [Throttle(Count = 15)]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `IFilterFactory` implementation will be the best choice.

```
public class ThrottleAttributeFactory : Attribute, IFilterFactory
{
    public string Count { get; set; }

    public bool IsReusable => false;

    public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var filter = serviceProvider.GetService<ThrottleAttribute>();

        filter.Count = Count;

        return filter;
    }
}
```

Then you can inject it to constructor

```
private readonly IConfiguration config;

public ThrottleAttribute(IConfiguration config)
{
    this.config = config;
}
```

You'll have to change  `[Throttle(Count = 15)]` to `[ThrottleAttributeFactory(Count = 15)]`

And don't forget to register IConfiguration and attribute in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...    
   services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
   services.AddScoped<ThrottleAttribute>();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

appsettings.json should be registered in DI so You can pass `IConfiguration` to `ThrottleAttribute` constructor and get value from it through DI, but You need to create factory to make it work:

```
public class ThrottleAttributeFactory: ActionFilterAttribute, IFilterFactory
{
    public string Count { get; set; }

    public bool IsReusable => false;

    public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var attribute = serviceProvider.GetService<ThrottleAttribute>();

        attribute.Count = Count;

        return attribute;
    }
}
```

Attribute:

```
public class ThrottleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public string Count { get; set; }

    public ThrottleAttribute(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
    //rest of code omitted
}
```

in Your method:

```
{
    var value = _config.GetValue<int>("json:key");
}
```

and in controller replace `[Throttle(Count = 15)]` with `[ThrottleAttributeFactory(Count = 15)]`.

Also register attribute: `services.AddScoped<ThrottleAttribute>();`

Comment: Hello, I already tried to do this, but with that solution I can not pass additional parameters to the filter ([Throttle(Count = 15)]), or I do not know how to do it.

Comment: It will give you a compilation error "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'config'"

Comment: What, did you even try this? why would you be able to do this, since when does you DI resolve attributes?

Comment: my bad, changed my answer

Comment: This may help too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

You could add a static property to your `Throttle` class and store the config value in there. Then in your startup class, you could set that value.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ThrottleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Count { get; set; }

    public static string ConfigCount { get; set; }

    private static MemoryCache Cache { get; } = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)
    {
        //Compare this.Count with GetValueFromAppSettings.json
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ThrottleAttribute.ConfigCount = Configuration.GetValue<int>("key");
}
```

Comment: This attribute is applied to multiple solutions what if the OP wanted to use different configurations per resource, and store multiple keys in the Config?