# An easy and convenient way to hide action method conditionally in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm looking for easy and convenient way to hide action methods in controllers in ASP.NET Core.
For some reason it's hard to find a complete and satisfactory answer.

For example, I want to hide specific action method in a specific controller for a given environment value (i.e. `IWebHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName != Development`).

I know about [ServiceFilterAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42424265/1752270), but this is the way to prevent execution of a method, and I prefer removing the action method completely from everywhere (as I said, conditionally), including generated swagger schemas. Something like `NonAction` attribute, but working with a runtime condition.
Still, if possible, I prefer using custom Attribute to decorate an action method.

Does anyone know any convenient ways to implement such behavior?

Comment: Calling a non-existent controller method will result in a 404. So, what about having a small piece of code at the beginning of the controller method which checks if this method can be called in the current hosting environment. If not, throw a 404

Comment: @AcidJunkie that's a fresh idea, but the method still will be in swagger.json and that's not good for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it with creating a custom `IApplicationModelConvention`

```
public class RemoveActionConvention : IApplicationModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
    {
        foreach (var controller in application.Controllers)
        {
            var toBeRemoved = new List<ActionModel>();
            foreach (var action in controller.Actions)
            {
                if (ShouldBeRemoved(action))
                {
                    toBeRemoved.Add(action);
                }
            }

            foreach (var action in toBeRemoved)
            {
                controller.Actions.Remove(action);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And add it to MVC conventions

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new RemoveActionConvention());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. What's even better, the action instance here already has the list of custom attributes to use in a filter.